# GTRR in first table or GTRR in alternative Table

Tags: filemaker

I have two tables, one for current amchines and one for achived machines. I have a page with a button that goes to related record and points to the machine table, if I move that record into the achive table the button no longer works.

Can I create a script which basically tries to go to related roecord in machines tables and nothing there go to related record in the archive table?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do what you want, including checking for related records before you go to one:

```
If Count(current machines::index) > 0
  Go to Related Record (from current machines)
Else If Count(archived machines::index) > 0
  Go to Related Record (from archived machines)
Else
  Error Message
End If
```

or just going to a related record and seeing if anything was found:

```
Set Error Capture On  // don't show an error message to the user
Go to Related Record (from current machines)
If Get(FoundCount) = 0
  Go to Related Record (from archived machines)
End If
Set Error Capture Off
```